# Creating, storing and outputting a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a code that uses a 2D array to store the house number and the number of children in the house, but I am having little trouble with the for loops and I don't really understand what the problem is. The dimensions of the array are the number of houses being the number of columns (this is a user input), and only two rows as the number of kids is inputted into the second row by the user. the code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int houses=0;
    int kids=0;
    printf("How many houses are there in the street?\n");
    scanf("%d", &houses);
    int KidsInStreet[houses][2];//Columns are the houses and the rows are 
the number of kids
    for(i=0;i<houses;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the value for KidsInStreet[%d][%d]:\n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &KidsInStreet[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<houses;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("House number:%d. Number of kid(s):%d\n", KidsInStreet[i]
[j]);
        }
    }


        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the requirement well you don't need 2 for loops. So your code is the following one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int i=0;
 int j=0;
 int houses=0;
 int kids=0;
 printf("How many houses are there in the street?\n");
 scanf("%d", &houses);
 int KidsInStreet[houses][2];//Columns are the houses and the rows are the number of kids

for(i = 1; i <= houses; i++)
{
    KidsInStreet [i][1] = i;
    printf("Enter the value for KidsInStreet[%d]:\n", i);
    scanf("%d", &KidsInStreet[i][2]);
}

for (i = 1; i <= houses; i++)   
{
    printf("House number:%d. Number of kid(s):%d\n", KidsInStreet[i][1], KidsInStreet[i][2]);   
}



}
```

Comment: Oh really, so does that store the data of the houses in a 2D array?

Comment: houses and kids, i mean?

Comment: I just update your code to your question. This is not really the way in which you can store data in a 2D array but is what you need. If you need to understand more about the concept of for loops and 2D array : https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/2d-arrays-in-c-example/

Comment: ok, thanks this really helps, especially the link, you have been a real help

Comment: Ok, so say if I wanted the sum of the kids now, could i just use KidsInStreet[i][2]+KidsInStreet[i+1][2], to get the total for the kids in the street?

Comment: To compute the sum of the kids you will have to write the following code: for ( i = 1; i <= houses; i++ ){sum = sum +KidsInStreet[i][2];} and int sum = 0

Comment: Also, as you mentioned that this is not really how you would store a 2d array, I think that it be better if I have a 2d array containing streets and houses as teh dimensions rather than kids and houses, and each individula data entry being kids, and I have figured out how tto do that thanks to your code, so thanks